# Implementing Panorama view using CATransform 3D

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I have set up a cubic view for implementing Panorama, so far all fine, But now i'm trapped in rotation. I don't know from where i should start my work, any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks For Listening.

Cheers, Arun